# css compatibility, in chrome one extra list item

Tags: html, css

I have html

```
<div id="leftDiv">
<ul>
    <li class="submenu_items" style="display: list-item;">
        <ul class="nomargin"> 
            <li><a href="/link1.php">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link2.php">Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>                
</ul>
</div>
```

css is

```
#leftDiv ul li.submenu_items ul.nomargin{
    margin:0;             
    list-style-image:none!important;
}
```

and I have

```
#leftDiv ul li{
   list-style-image: url("/images/spacer.png");
}
```

in ff everything looks fine but in chrome and opera I have extra image from ul li bg(/images/spacer.png) it looks like I have one extra list item in chrome and opera

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eruE7/)

You actually have 3 `<li>` nodes, your CSS isnt accomodating correctly for your desired output.

You may want to change your CSS to:

```
#leftDiv ul{
   list-style:none;
}
#leftDiv ul li.submenu_items ul.nomargin{
   margin:0; list-style:none!important; 
} 
#leftDiv ul ul li{ 
   list-style-image: url(/images/spacer.png); 
}
```

Comment: I removed completely display: list-item; and changed ul li to ul ul li as you suggested but remains the same.

Comment: Hmmm...I've checked the code provided and seems OK in chrome, this may be a conflict with some other CSS/HTML you have?

Comment: Try this:  #leftDiv ul{
    list-style:none;
}
#leftDiv ul li.submenu_items ul.nomargin{
    margin:0;             
    list-style:none!important;
}

#leftDiv ul ul li{
   list-style-image: url(/images/spacer.png);
}